# How can I combine the data of muliple rows into single row in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have the below data

| Id | Sub Id | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 20 | 25.65 |
| 10 | 30 | 56.56 |
| 10 | 40 | 784.56 |
| 10 | 50 | 56.24 |

I want to filter this data on sub_id and display all the selected sub_id values in one single row.

So if i want the value of sub id 20, 30 and 50 then the output what I need is like

| Id | Sub_Id_20_value | sub_id_30_value | sub_id_50_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 25.65 | 56.56 | 56.24 |

i can do that by using self join probably, but looking for a smarter solution.

Comment: How many sub ID values can there be and is this number fixed?

Comment: number of sub_id can be quite a lot but the ones which i need to retrieve are fixed. say 5 out of 50 is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE sub_id WHEN 20 THEN value END) AS sub_id_20_value,
       MAX(CASE sub_id WHEN 30 THEN value END) AS sub_id_30_value,
       MAX(CASE sub_id WHEN 50 THEN value END) AS sub_id_50_value
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY id
```

or a `PIVOT`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
PIVOT (
  MAX(value) FOR sub_id IN (
    20 AS sub_id_20_value,
    30 AS sub_id_30_value,
    50 AS sub_id_50_value
  )
)
```

Which both output:

> | ID | SUB_ID_20_VALUE | SUB_ID_30_VALUE | SUB_ID_50_VALUE |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 10 | 25.65 | 56.56 | 56.24 |

*SQL fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0be2c3/1)*